# Using double counters to synchronize in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I have a strange synchronization architecture going on and I am looking for an elegant solution. I already had a solution but I cannot say anything about its validity and its also a little ugly. So here is the problem, hopefully someone can help me.

There are 2 groups of tasks that can be started and run. Each task has its own thread. These two groups both extend from one super class that takes care of the synchronization part. I will call these two groups Group A and Group B for simplicity.

Conditions:

- If there are only Group B tasks running then they can run at the same time and they do not interfere with each other.
- If a Group A task is started* then the constructor for a Group B task should fail with an exception. Any number of Group A tasks can be created even if a Group A task is already running
- A Group A task cannot execute until all current Group B tasks have finished. (* from above)
- Only 1 Group A task can run at a time. They must be queued. (It is optional to block Group B tasks between the running of the two Group A tasks as long as the previous conditions still apply)

I believe my method works but I do not like the way it works because of the many different synchronization points that it uses, and the fact that I have a sleep while waiting for the counter. Anyway the code is below

```
public abstract class LockableTask<Params> extends AsyncTask {

private final boolean groupA;
private static Boolean locked = false;
private static final Semaphore semLock = new Semaphore(1);
private static int count = 0;

public LockableTask(boolean groupA) {
    this.groupA = groupA;
    synchronized (locked) {
        if (locked && !groupA) {
            throw new InputException("We are locked, please wait");
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected final AsyncReturn doInBackground(Params... params) {
    if (!groupA) {
        synchronized (locked) {
            count++;
        }
    }

    try {
        if (groupA) {
            semLock.acquireUninterruptibly();
            synchronized (locked) {
                locked = true;
            }

            while (true) {
                synchronized (locked) {
                    if (count == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
        return runInBackground(params);
    } finally {
        synchronized (locked) {
            if (groupA) {
                locked = false;
            } else {
                count--;
            }
        }

        if (groupA) {
            semLock.release();
        }
    }
}

protected abstract AsyncReturn runInBackground(Params... params);
}
```

If someone has a nicer solution even if just barely nicer that would be great

Comment: Consider a groupA task that starts execution. Just before it reaches the `semLock.acquire` statement, it loses CPU. A groupB task can get created now, since `locked` is not yet set to true. But this is a violation of your requirements. In fact, the groupB task can even start running - say it gets to the `if (!groupA)` statement - and then lose the CPU. Say now the thread running the groupA task is woken up again - it proceeds, noticing that the count is 0. When the groupB task wakes up, it increments count and will proceed too. Thus groupA task and the groupB task both will run concurrently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an upper bound on the number of simultaneous Group B tasks (even if it's very large), you should be able to achieve the rules you describe with a single semaphore.

```
int UPPER_BOUND=1000000;
Semaphore s=new Semaphore(UPPER_BOUND);
```

Group A task:

```
s.acquireUninterruptibly(UPPER_BOUND);
......
s.release(UPPER_BOUND);
```

Group B task:

```
if (!s.tryAcquire())
    throw new WhateverException("Upper bound of Bs reached or A running");
......
s.release();
```

End result: whilst any group B are running, A cannot acquire the number of permits it requires.  Once it does, no B can acquire a permit and neither can any other A.

Comment: unfortunately there should be no upper bound

Comment: Not even, say, 1,000,000?  It can be a really high upper bound without affecting the function of the thing.

Comment: Actually this is not too bad, but if I acquire the lock in the constructor, and the task does not run, then it wont be released.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want to use a [`ReadWriteLock`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html). Let each task of group A acquire its [`readLock()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html#readLock%28%29) and each task of group B acquire its [`writeLock()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html#writeLock%28%29).

This way any number of Group A tasks can run at once, but only ever one task of Group B can run (at which point no other Group A tasks can run).

```
ReadWriteLock rwLock = getSharedReadWriteLock();
Lock lock = groupA ? rwLock.readLock() : rwLock.writeLock();
lock.lock();
try {
  return runInBackground(params);
} finally {
  lock.unlock();
}
```

Comment: I too was thinking ReadWriteLock, but Stoyan wants B's constructor to fail rather than block.

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, but he can easily do that with `tryLock()`.

Comment: I didn't find a `tryLock()` in `ReadWriteLock` before, but now I've got it.  It's `ReentrantReadWriteLock.readLock().tryLock()`.

Comment: @Karmastan: no, but you call `writeLock()` on the `ReadWriteLock` to get the write lock and call `tryLock()` on **that** `Lock` object.

Comment: Wait, shouldn't Group A tasks get the write lock and Group B tasks get the read lock?  I think your answer has it backwards.

Comment: ReadWriteLock looks to be almost what I want however it does not wait for all Group B(read) tasks to finish before running a Group A(write) task. And furthermore I think I would need some more synchronization around the tryLock call because this would be done in the constructor but the read lock would be acquired in a different thread at a later time, so I could still spin there waiting for a read lock, but the task might be invalid after the Group A task finished.

Comment: @Stoyan: of course it waits! The `writeLock()` is exclusive. As long as that is held, no other lock (no further `writeLocks()` or `readLock()` can be held!). And adding synchronization (a low-level concurrency tool) to a `ReadWriteLock` doesn't sound good. Also, I don't really understand why you want to check the locks in the constructor: why not simply check them *when you need them*.

Comment: @joachim When I said waits I mean I want the write lock to wait for all read locks to be released. The reason why I want to check the lock in the constructor is that i want to make all new Group B tasks fail to be constructed if there is a write lock waiting or active. I don't think I can acquire the read lock in the constructor since the release would happen on a different thread.